# How do I know that a .npz file was compressed or not?

Tags: python, numpy, python-zipfile

Given a .npz file from `np.savez` or `np.savez_compressed`, when it got loaded by `np.load`, is there any way to check whether the file was compressed or not?

I tried to look though [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html) and [GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7dceee5195232c40e31497eca429c86fba15db18/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L103). It didn't tell me anything but how the file is compressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.load` returns a `NpzFile` object.

- It has a [`zip` attribute](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7dceee5195232c40e31497eca429c86fba15db18/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L198) which is a [`ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) object.
- Which has an [`infolist()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist) method which returns a list of [`ZipInfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipinfo-objects) objects.
- Which has a `compress_type` attribute which contains the compression method used.

If `np.savez` was used, the compression type is [`ZIP_STORED`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZIP_STORED), if `np.savez_compressed` was used, the compression type is [`ZIP_DEFLATED`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) ([relevant source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7dceee5195232c40e31497eca429c86fba15db18/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L728)).

So to wrap it up:

```
import numpy
import zipfile

def is_compressed(npz_file):
    zip_infos = npz_file.zip.infolist()
    if len(zip_infos) == 0:
        raise RuntimeError("Did not find ZipInfos unexpectedly")
    compress_type = zip_infos[0].compress_type
    if compress_type == zipfile.ZIP_STORED:
        return False
    elif compress_type == zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED:
        return True
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unexpected compression type")

# Example
a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
numpy.savez("uncompressed.npz", a)
numpy.savez_compressed("compressed.npz", a)
u = numpy.load("uncompressed.npz")
c = numpy.load("compressed.npz")
print(is_compressed(u))  # False
print(is_compressed(c))  # True
```